# MongoDB - Save vs Update for specific fields in document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mean-stack, mean

Using the MEAN stack, I'm attempting to have an admin account update another user's information, in this case, their title/role on the site.  The problem I have is that the only function available when editing a user is the save() function.  It might be that I can utilize the update function, and if that is the case please let me know, but it doesn't look possible:

[image]

The problem arises that when the user is saved, it creates a new document, and overwrites the user's password and salt to some value.  I'd like to be able to call an "update" function that will only update the one field, but I can't figure out how to.  Is there a way to do this with the save function?

Relevant Code:

```
exports.updateUserRoles = function(req, res) { 
    var currUser = req.body;
    User.findById(currUser._id, function(err, user) {
    //user.roles = currUser.roles;
    user.save( { _id : '56467b28ba57d8d890242cfa', roles : 'admin' } );

    //THE BELOW WAS A PREVIOUS ATTEMPT

    /*user.save( function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).send({
                message: errorHandler.getErrorMessage(err)
            });
        } else {
            res.jsonp(user);
            console.log('test2');
        }
    });*/
});
};
```

Trying something else that seems very close, but still not quite there yet.

Here's what I'm running:

```
exports.updateUserRoles = function(req, res) { 
    var currUser = req.body;
    User.findById(currUser._id, function(err, user) {
        //user.roles = currUser.roles;
        //user.roles.set(0, 'admin');
        console.log('test');
        user.update(
            { _id: '56467b28ba57d8d890242cfa' },
            {
              $set: {
                roles: 'admin',
              },
            }
        );
        console.log('test2');
    });
};
```

Upon hitting the user.update line, we have the user in the local variables, seen:

[image]

user.update goes into this Document.prototype.update function, seen:

[image]

The args look to be building right, which _id we are targeting and what the action is, seen:

[image]

But then after running, nothing seems to change.  I'm very much stumped.

Answer (score 0):

For updates various fields in mongodb you can use update with different atomic operators, like $set, $unset, $push etc.
Example:

```
var updateUserRoles = function(db, callback) {
   db.collection('users').updateOne(
      { "_id", : "user_id", },
      { $set: { "password": "new_password" } }, 
      function(err, results) {
         console.log(results);
         callback();
      }
   );
};
```